# How do I prove this trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry

It is as follows:
$$\tan 3x=\frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$

I have tried using Symbolab's solver, but it does not show the steps, only that it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know an identity that says $\tan(x+y) = \text{a certain function of } \tan x \text{ and } \tan y \text{ ?} $

If so you can write
$$
\tan(3x) = \tan (x + 2x) = \cdots
$$
and apply that identity in the case where $y = 2x$.

Next, you have to deal with $\tan(2x)$.  Now you can write
$$
\tan(2x) = \tan(x+x) =\cdots
$$
and apply the identity again in the case where $y=x$.

If you don't know the identity that says $\tan(x+y) = \text{a certain function of } \tan x \text{ and } \tan y,$ then you should learn that before attempting the problem you asked about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!